# __str__ method not being called when printing

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a simple sql builder class, however when I try to print the output of `import_` it does not seem to return the content of `get_sql` even though its in `__str__` function. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Query(object):
    """
    Query builder entry functions
    """
    @classmethod
    def _builder(cls):
        return QueryBuilder()

    @classmethod
    def import_(cls, source_type):
        return cls._builder().import_(source_type)


class QueryBuilder(object):
    """
    Query Builder is the main class that generates sql
    """
    def __init__(self, quote_char='"'):
        self._from = []
        self._import = None
        self._source_type = None
        self.quote_char = quote_char

    def import_(self, source_type):
        if source_type == SourceType.XML:
            raise KeyError('Importing a XML is not supported')
        self._source_type = source_type

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_sql(quote_char='"')

    def get_sql(self):
        if not (self._import):
            return 'test'
        return 'e'
```

Print script:

```
importQuery = Query.import_(sourceTypeEnum)
print(importQuery)
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE or Jupyter? Just writing the variable name without calling `print` will instead invoke `__repr__`.

Comment: have added print script now

Comment: factory pattern functions needs to `return self`, that way you can state `importQuery = Query.import_..`. Otherwise you can create objects only using the class constructor.

Comment: Please don't write code like this. Python is not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `return self` at the end of your `QueryBuilder.import_` method, otherwise it will return `None` and therefore your `importQuery` will be `None` - not an instance of your `QueryBuilder` as you expected.

Comment: Also, only the `return self` will allow chaining `import_` calls, making it a proper builder pattern.